# Format the output of a string

Tags: c#

here 
 string strScore="2"; or
 string strScore="2.45656"
 now here i am checking the condition if it is

```
 double value = double.Parse(strScore);

strScore = value.ToString("##.##");
```

**2.45656 like this then i am  showing the output as
2.45**

if the input is
string strScore="2"; 
 then the ouput is shown as "2"

**but now i need  to show the output has  2.00**
 how can i format the  code like this  based on the condition

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
strScore = value.ToString("0.00");
```

The `#` means that the digit is optional and leading/trailing zeros will not be displayed. If you write `0` then the digit is not optional: leading and trailing zeros will be displayed.